# Promise and async pipe and Angular ngfor

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, promise, ionic3

**Update:**

Below solution of mine is also working. I had a `local storage` corruption or something like that.That was the reason for not working.

**Question:**

Can you tell me how to use `promise`/`async` pipe and `ngfor`? I have tried as shown below.But it is not working.

*html*

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let c of contacts | async">
        <ion-label fixed>c.name</ion-label>
 </ion-item>
```

*ts*

```
  contacts: Promise<Contact[]>;
  constructor() {
    this.getContacts()
  }

  getContacts() {
    this.contacts = this.storage.get('contacts').then((val: Contact[]) => {
      console.log('log', val);
      return val;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this on your `.ts` file:

```
getContacts() {
   this.contacts = this.storage.get('contacts');
}
```

this way in your html the async pipe will subscribe to the promise

Comment: Workaround works perfectly. But somehow if i have a return promise in a service, when i apply the async the app hangs

Comment: OPs solution is already correct and this code effectively does the same. This answer doesn't contain a fix and I don't understand why people upvote.